# Deepcopy Errors in pip install, pandas, selenium, everywhere

Tags: python

I've been recently getting deepcopy errors on my Windows 2008 R2 server running python 2.7.

Even a simple pip install -U selenium gives this error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
__import__('pip._vendor.packaging.requirements')
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip._vendor.pyparsing import (
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3462, in <module>
_reBracketExpr = Literal("[") + Optional("^").setResultsName("negate") + Group( OneOrMore( _charRange | _singleChar ) ).setResultsName("body") + "]"
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 884, in setResultsName
newself = self.copy()
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 858, in copy
cpy = copy.copy( self )
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

When I run the command mydriver=webdriver.Firefox() in python shell, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",line 51, in __init__
self.profile = firefox_profile or FirefoxProfile()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 67, in __init__
self.default_preferences = copy.deepcopy(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'
```

I get similar errors while importing pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thing can happen when a `copy.py` or `copy.pyc` exists in the folder you run your Python scripts. So when you `import copy` it actually imports the `copy.py` in your working directory. Make sure don't use `copy.py` as your filename.